# linq: Get Max value, then get an associated property of that result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects that have properties of Date (DateTime) and Status (String).

I need to get the value of Status that is associated with the most recent Date.

I can get the most recent date with this:

```
var MostRecentDate = ListOfObjects.Max(x => x.MyDate);
```

However, how can I get the value of Status that is associated with MostRecentDate?

Any ideas are very welcome. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using OrderByDescending

```
var MostRecent = ListOfObjects.OrderBydescending(x => x.MyDate).First();
```

Comment: Yes, get the object, then use that to get the properties. Thanks!